# Does runnable scheduled with Handler.postDelayed wait till the current runnable finishes?

Tags: android

My code is like following

```
mNonUIHandler.post(runnable1);
mNonUIHandler.postDelayed(runnable2, 20*1000);
```

Suppose runnable1 takes 30 seconds to finish. Will runnable2 run at time (now + 30 seconds) till runnable1 finishes or run at time (now + 20 seconds) before runnable1 finishes?

Comment: Neither. Your app will crash with an Application Not Responding error, as you are tying up the main application thread too long.

Comment: I updated my post to indicate that the Handler is a non-UI Handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handler you post it to runs on the Thread it was created on.  A thread can only do one thing at a time.  So yes, it will wait until the first one (and any other events in the event queue) are finished before running the new one.  If you need it to run immediately, you need to create a new Thread rather than posting a message.